# Subsetting observations with grouping some features

Tags: r

I have a dataset like below:

```
date,       time,product,shop_id

20140104    900 Banana  18  
20140104    900 Banana  19  
20140104    924 Banana  18  
20140104    929 Banana  18  
20140104    932 Banana  20  
20140104    948 Banana  18
```

and i need to extract the observations with different `product`, and different `shop_id`

so, i need to group the observations by `product+shop_id`

here is my code:

```
library(plyr)
  d_ply( shop, .( product,shop_id  ),table   )
 print(p)
```

unfortunately, it prints `null`

dataset:

```
date=c(20140104,20140104,20140104,20140104,20140104)
time=c(924  ,900,854,700,1450)
product=c(Banana    ,Banana ,Banana ,Banana ,Banana)
shop_id=c(18,18,18,19,20)
shop<-data.frame(date=date,time=time,product=product,shop_id=shop_id)
```

the output should be

```
         date,    time, product, shop_id


        20140104    900 Banana  19  
        20140104    932 Banana  20  
        20140104    948 Banana  18
```

Comment: What is the logic of selecting the given rows with `time` 948 and 932

Comment: they have diferent `shop_id`. every selected observation should have either either unique product or shop_id, or both

Comment: But why do you choose time 948 instead of 900 when it is Banana from shop 18?

Comment: Or do you want just unique combinations of shop_id and product and the date and time is irrelevant?

Comment: @ira u right. i just want the **first unique** combination

Comment: @user5363938 please highlight it in your question

Answer (score 0):

We can do

```
library(tidyverse)
shop %>%
   group_by(product, shop_id) %>% 
   mutate(n = n()) %>% 
   group_by(time) %>% 
   arrange(n) %>%
   slice(1) %>%
   group_by(product, shop_id) %>% 
   arrange(-time) %>%
   slice(1) %>% 
   select(-n) %>%
   arrange(time)
#      date  time product shop_id
#      <int> <int>   <chr>   <int>
#1 20140104   900  Banana      19
#2 20140104   932  Banana      20
#3 20140104   948  Banana      18
```

Comment: I wish people stopped condoning this anti-pattern of importing unused libraries. Be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

In order to take only first unique combination, just use [aggregate](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/aggregate.html) from package `stats`:

```
> aggregate(shop, by=list(shop$product, shop$shop_id), FUN=function(x){x[1]})

Group.1 Group.2     date time product shop_id
1  Banana      18 20140104  924  Banana      18
2  Banana      19 20140104  700  Banana      19
3  Banana      20 20140104 1450  Banana      20
```

Explanation: My `FUN=function(x){x[1]}` takes only first element in case of collision

To drop "Group.1", "Group.2" or other columns:

```
> res <- aggregate(shop, by=list(shop$product, shop$shop_id), FUN=function(x){x[1]})
> res[ , !(names(res) %in% c("Group.1", "Group.2"))]
      date time product shop_id
1 20140104  924  Banana      18
2 20140104  700  Banana      19
3 20140104 1450  Banana      20
```

P.S. Your dataset provided is inconsistent with examples you required, so that's why there is a difference in numbers.

P.S.2 If you want to get all data in case of collision:

```
> aggregate(shop, by=list(shop$product, shop$shop_id), FUN="identity")
  Group.1 Group.2                         date          time product    shop_id
1  Banana      18 20140104, 20140104, 20140104 924, 900, 854 1, 1, 1 18, 18, 18
2  Banana      19                     20140104           700       1         19
3  Banana      20                     20140104          1450       1         20
```

If you want to mark collisions:

```
> aggregate(shop, by=list(shop$product, shop$shop_id), FUN=function(x){if (length(x) > 1) NA else x})
  Group.1 Group.2     date time product shop_id
1  Banana      18       NA   NA      NA      NA
2  Banana      19 20140104  700       1      19
3  Banana      20 20140104 1450       1      20
```

If you want to exclude non-unique rows:

```
> res <- aggregate(shop, by=list(shop$product, shop$shop_id), FUN=function(x){if (length(x) > 1) NULL else x})

> res[res$product != "NULL", !(names(res) %in% c("Group.1", "Group.2"))]
      date time product shop_id
2 20140104  700       1      19
3 20140104 1450       1      20
```

If you want to avoid coerce from String to Int (for product), use ""/"NULL"/"NA" instead of NULL/NA.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using dplyr as follows:

```
# create the sample dataset
date=c(20140104,20140104,20140104,20140104,20140104)
time=c(924  ,900,854,700,1450)
product=c("Banana","Banana","Banana","Banana","Banana")
shop_id=c(18,18,18,19,20)
shop<-data.frame(date=date,time=time,product=product,shop_id=shop_id)

# load a dplyr library
library(dplyr)

# take shop data
shop %>%
        # group by product, shop id, date
        group_by(product, shop_id, date) %>%
        # for each such combination, find the earliest time
        summarise(time = min(time)) %>%
        # group by product, shop id
        group_by(product, shop_id) %>%
        # for each combination of product & shop id
        # return the earliest date and time recorded on the earliest date
        summarise(date = min(date), time = time[date == min(date)])
```